# how to convert the Index colum to normal column.?1st 2colm are index & I applied df_agg.index & I am getting column where I need only Date in Txn_Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

```
                         Txn_Date                       Expected out
```

Acc_No    new_Txn_date

```
121      1/1/2011       (121, 2011-04-01 00:00:00)      2011-04-01
         2/1/2011       (121, 2011-04-01 00:00:00)      2011-04-01
         4/1/2011       (121, 2011-04-01 00:00:00)      2011-04-01

123      10/1/2011      (123, 2011-10-01 00:00:00)      2011-10-01 
         20/1/2011      (123, 2011-20-01 00:00:00)      2011-20-01
         04/1/2011      (123, 2011-04-01 00:00:00)      2011-04-01
```

I am expecting only dates in Txn_date?how to do it, I just applied df.index on the data frame but it's showing both indexes combined but I wanted only the date in my txn_date column

Comment: You should read the doc for [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)...

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})
>>> 
Out[23]: 
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
df.reset_index()
>>>
   index  a
0      0  1
1      1  2
2      2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing.

```
index, df['Txn_Date'] = zip(*df['Txn_Date'])
```

where df is your dataframe df_agg as shown in your question.

But please check that 'Txn Date' must contain 2 element tuple throughout the dataframe.

Comment: getting answer like this <zip object at 0x000001CDBBAE2A40>                                                                                 
<zip object at 0x000001CDBBAE2A40>